# AWS: Using a KMS-encrypted master password to create a RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform, amazon-kms

When creating a new RDS instance on AWS via the aws cli tools, is it possible to use a master password which is encrypted with an AWS KMS key?
E.g. using this command: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance.html

I'm asking because I don't want to store clear text passwords in my dev environment (using terraform or cloud formation), instead encrypted values which are transparently decrypted by the according AWS components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to do this with the CLI you could always encrypt the password with a KMS key and then run two commands to decrypt the password and create the database.

So something like this might work:

```sh
aws rds create-instance ... \
--master-username admin-user \
--master-user-password `aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://path/to/kms/encrypted/file/with/password --output text --query Plaintext | base64 --decode`
```

If you wanted to still use Terraform for creating your database instances then I've [previously answered a question along similar lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42086344/2291321). Although that question is more concerned around the database being stored in a remote state file.

If you were equally concerned about keeping the password in your code then I'd consider simply using a variable for your password and then [passing that in on the CLI](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html#command-line-flags) or using an [environment variable](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables).

Equally you could use the [`aws_kms_secret` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/kms_secret.html) to decrypt your password on the fly. That will leak the password to logs and state files though:

```
$ echo -n 'master-password' > plaintext-password
$ aws kms encrypt \
> --key-id ab123456-c012-4567-890a-deadbeef123 \
> --plaintext fileb://plaintext-example \
> --encryption-context foo=bar \
> --output text --query CiphertextBlob
AQECAHgaPa0J8WadplGCqqVAr4HNvDaFSQ+NaiwIBhmm6qDSFwAAAGIwYAYJKoZIhvcNAQcGoFMwUQIBADBMBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHgYJYIZIAWUDBAEuMBEEDI+LoLdvYv8l41OhAAIBEIAfx49FFJCLeYrkfMfAw6XlnxP23MmDBdqP8dPp28OoAQ==
```

And then in Terraform:

```
data "aws_kms_secret" "db" {
  secret {
    name    = "master_password"
    payload = "AQECAHgaPa0J8WadplGCqqVAr4HNvDaFSQ+NaiwIBhmm6qDSFwAAAGIwYAYJKoZIhvcNAQcGoFMwUQIBADBMBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHgYJYIZIAWUDBAEuMBEEDI+LoLdvYv8l41OhAAIBEIAfx49FFJCLeYrkfMfAw6XlnxP23MmDBdqP8dPp28OoAQ=="

    context {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds" {
  master_username = "root"
  master_password = "${data.aws_kms_secret.db.master_password}"

  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rocksteady! I tried the `aws_kms_secret` already but this doesn't work as expected, I asked the devs to clarify on the documentation here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12800. This would indeed be my preferred way when using Terraform. I'm still researching it.

Comment: If that's not working for you then, as mentioned, you could run a shell script that grabs the decrypted plaintext from an encrypted file and exports it as an environment variable to be used by Terraform when it runs.

Comment: Yet the interesting point here is: You cannot simply pass an encrypted password to RDS along with the Key ID and expect RDS to decrypt it transparently for the according use case, correct?

Comment: Correct but that's because AWS' APIs don't support that (yet).