# Keeping secrets out of Terraform state

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to avoid having secrets in Terraform state.

Is there a better way of setting an RDS password from a secret in Secrets Manager that does this?

```
resource "null_resource" "master_password" {
  triggers = {
    db_host = module.myrdsdatabase.cluster_id
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<TOF
    password=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myrdscreds | jq '.SecretString | fromjson | .password' | tr -d '"')
    aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier ${module.myrdsdatabase.cluster_id} --master-user-password $password --apply-immediately
    TOF

    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Terraform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform and cleartext password in (remote) state file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076971/terraform-and-cleartext-password-in-remote-state-file)

Comment: Terraform version is 0.14

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Was any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 16):

There is no concrete solution to this issue. There is nearly 7 year old, still active, discussion on [TF github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/516) about handling secrets in TF.

In your question you are already avoiding `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version` which is good practice. `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version` **will not protect** your secrets from being in plain text in TF state file!

Generally, there are two things people do to keep the secrets secret:

1. Store your TF state in a **remote** backend. Such as S3 with **strict** IAM and bucket policy controls, along with encryption at rest.
2. Use **external** procedure to set the passwords for your database. One way is `local-exec`, other could be using remote lambda through `aws_lambda_invocation`.

Other ways are possible, such as creating RDS databases through CloudFormation (CFN) from your TF. CFN has a proper way of accessing secret manager securely through dynamic references.

Answer (score 2):

We have to accept that the secrets are in the state and manage access and encryption to the remote state accordingly.

You can get a value right out of secrets manager with the [aws_secretsmanager_secret_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/secretsmanager_secret_version#handling-key-value-secret-strings-in-json) data source

your local-exec can be simplified a bit by using jq `--raw-format` or `-r`

```
 password=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id myrdscreds | jq -r .SecretString | jq -r .password)
```

I prefer to fetch and then pass in the secret in a variable from a build script, rather than local-exec. It seems cleaner, in some cases the trigger on the null resource may not fire when the secret value has been changed.

Comment: While this is a known limitation of Terraform, we do not need to accept it. There are alternative tools, and we can contribute to improving this in Terraform

Answer (score -4):

The current possible workaround is using SecretHub

https://secrethub.io/docs/guides/terraform/

but again as @marcin said no native support from Terraform, and the idea to encrypt your state file and restrict access to the backend eg. S3

another way I would do this by using `aws cli` outside of terraform to rest the password and upload it to secret manager.

Comment: Notice on their website: SecretHub is shutting down on January 1st 2023.