# Avoid writing secrets in Terraform state, in a custom provider

Tags: go, security, terraform, cryptography

We are implementing a custom provider, and we would like to avoid storing sensitive values in Terraform state. Let's say we have:

```
resource my_secret_resource {
  secret_value = var.secret_value
}
```

We know that it's possible to use `StateFunc` to store a transformation of this value. Let's say we do this:

```
"secret_value": {
  Type:      schema.TypeString,
  StateFunc: func stateFuncEncrypting(v interface{}) string {
    return encrypt(hash(v))   
  },
},
```

We don't want to just `hash`, because it's not very safe, but a good `encrypt` produces different values each time, thus confusing Terraform:

```
$ terraform apply

...

╷
│ Error: Provider produced inconsistent final plan
│ 
│ When expanding the plan for my_secret_resource.test1 to include new values learned so far during apply, provider
│ "xxx" produced an invalid new value for .secret_value: was
│ cty.StringVal("TNwbQAAABBcHGEnvVmb..."),
│ but now
│ cty.StringVal("xuwrHk5COAAAADAJewY...").
│ 
│ This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own issue tracker.
```

Is there any way to tweak `StateFunc`, `DiffSuppressFunc`, `CustomizeDiff` or other Terraform pieces, to accomplish this?

---

Related posts:

- [Keeping secrets out of Terraform state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163498/keeping-secrets-out-of-terraform-state)
- [How can I implement it using DiffSuppressFunc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75292022/how-can-i-implement-it-using-diffsuppressfunc)

Related TF issues:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30469
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/516

Comment: I assume you have not already seen https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/best-practices/sensitive-state since `Sensitive` is undefined. Besides that is it not the responsibility of the provider plugin to authenticate for, authorize for, and/or manage secrets. The state would need to be safeguarded independently.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard Thank you very much, yes, we know about that. Anyway, users of our provider don't want to have to safeguard the state. So we're trying to find a workaround. We've found some, but they're not ellegant.

Comment: Ok then just spitballing here but have you considered importing the Vault API module and then using its bindings to the transit secret engine for the encryption/decryption? I understand that maybe the users do not want to be responsible for secrets, but other provider plugins make the same demands, and there are tools available already to handle this leakage. I assume you are beholden to someone else's opinion other than your own for the direction of the implementation, so I am sorry about that.

Comment: Alternatively there are probably other encryption/decryption Go modules available that support AES-256-GCM besides the Vault transit engine, or you could develop your own using that cipher algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

In general, with today's Terraform there is no way for a resource type to accept an argument without that argument's value being stored in the state. The `StateFunc` mechanism in the SDK, and various other things like it, are there primarily to allow distinguishing normalization differences from meaningful differences, rather than for storing materially different values.

Terraform's consistency checks effectively block such efforts because any references to that argument from expressions elsewhere in the module will assume that the value remains consistent in meaning between the validate, plan, and apply phases, and (unless the desired state is being intentionally changed by the author) from one plan/apply round to the next.

Some other providers with similar requirements have implemented solutions whose common theme is passing the value *indirectly* rather than directly. For example, you can potentially make the provider argument take a path to a file on disk which contains the secret value and then load it within the provider code -- though of course that would require the sensitive value to hit disk -- or you could encourage operators to provide the sensitive value via an environment variable when it's needed, or various other kinds of indirection that mean that the sensitive value is never handled directly by Terraform Core.

These solutions are, of course, imperfect and cumbersome. Hopefully one day Terraform will have a more explicit means of solving this problem, but I would suggest not trying to trick today's Terraform into allowing this because anything you *do* manage to achieve would likely end up depending on implementation details or bugs that are not intended as guarantees, and thus lead to a provider that is brittle when used across different versions of Terraform.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed response, Martin. We would like the solution to be as consistent with TF as possible. For now, the best idea we've got is: in `StateFunc`, apply some kind of safe hashing, like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), to the sensitive values. They HMAC key would come from the provider (not stored in the state). This way, we're storing the values in the state, just transformed. It's not possible to recover the original value from the hash but, AFAIK, TF doesn't need to do that.